# Is it possible to iterate over a collection with a specified starting element without using Skip or Take?

Tags: c#, for-loop, collections

If I have a collection like the following:

`0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15`

is it possible to iterate over these elements in the normal order it would, but start at a particular element?  I don't want to leave any out, and the collection, as is, is important to keep unchanged.  But for an intermediate step, I need to gather information that pertains to those elements in this order: 0, 15, 14 (aka iterating in decreasing order, starting at 0, and wrapping back around to get 15 and then 14, in that order)?

Maybe the foreach loop won't work for me, but I'm struggling to determine a way to do this most efficiently.

### To Clarify:

With any collection of ints of type `List<int>` where it is guaranteed that I have the integers from 0 to some number, I would like to iterate through these items in either increasing or decreasing order, specifying a starting element, and have the iteration wrap around to make sure all elements are iterated on exactly once.

### What I've Learned So Far:

I really appreciate all the help I've received already.  I think I'm finding out that developing another collection with the elements I want and the order I want is necessary for what I want to do.  I'll keep assessing everyone's suggestions so far and keep everyone posted.

### What Worked For Me:

Please refer to the answer that I flagged as most useful and what I came up with here to expand off that by making a similar static method that gives what I'm looking for in the Increasing direction when needed:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetRangeIncreasing<T>(IList<T> source, int startPosition, int count)
{
    var index = startPosition;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < count; counter++)
    {
        yield return source[index];

        index = (index + 1)%source.Count;
        if (index > source.Count - 1)
            index -= source.Count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your collection implement `IList`/`ICollection`, or only `IEnumerable`?

Comment: is it possible to just use a regular for loop and access them by index?

Comment: it is of the type `List<int>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like reverse iterator is what you're really looking for. The easiest way to get that is using `IList<T>`, because it supports index access.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetRangeDecreasing<T>(IList<T> source, int startPosition, int count)
{
    var index = startPosition;
    for (int  counter = 0; counter < count; counter++)
    {
        yield return source[index];

        index = (index - 1) % source.Count;
        if (index < 0)
            index += source.Count;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
IList<int> input = Enumerable.Range(0, 16).ToArray();
var output = GetRangeDecreasing(input, 0, 3);
```

`output` will contain 3 elements: `0`, `15` and `14`.

Comment: This is definitely looking like it will work for me!  Thank you so much!

Comment: I was also able to use your example to come up with a GetRangeIncreasing method for when I need that.  Again, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The collection will need to support a indexer so you can do `item[i]` on it and get the element you want. If that is possible just use a `for` loop that counts down but grab your special case of 0 first.

```
static IEnumerable<int> GetInSpecialOrder(YourCollectionType items)
{
    if(items.Length > 0)
        yield return items[0];

    for (int i = items.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        yield return items[i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  My issue with your suggestion is that it is not the case that I will want to start at 0 every time.  Another example of the portion of the collection I would want would be `1, 0, 15, 14`.

Comment: @JakeSmith in that case use [MarcinJuraszek's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20959857/80274) as it is doing the exact same thing as mine but is more flexible with a dynamic starting point and number of elements to take.

Comment: I'll give it a shot and see what I can come up with.  I'm going to look up the `yield` keyword first to make sure I understand it well enough.  I really appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming any indexed collection:

```
// array for simplicity
int[] myArr = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };

// get indexes 0, 14, 15
var myInts = myArr.Where((n, i) => i == 0 || i => 14)
   .ToArray();
```

Reordering the array is as simple as poking the values from one index into another. This seems like a very specialized requirement; however, this example shows how to select array (indexed) values by the indexer itself using LINQ.

Comment: How does it goes with *I need to gather information that pertains to those elements in this order: 0, 15, 14* from OP?

Comment: The example shows acting on a specific index. The same can be done on `n` rather than `i`.

Comment: Yes, but you wan't be able to start from `0` and go back to `15` and `14` using your approach.

Comment: What the OP wants is two-fold: 1) be able to get indexed values from a collection without `.Take(x)` or `.Skip(x)`; and, 2) reverse 2 of the values. First is easy but the 2nd requirement is antithesis since it doesn't take all values and reverse the order.

Answer (score 0):

You can just reverse the order of the collection, and add the 0 index item to the top.

See Reverse:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  Please see me update with the clarification and what I've learned so far...